# CRM 2011 - Connect to CRM using SSIS - status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to connect to CRM 2011 using SQL 2008 R2 Integration Services - the goal is, to load data into CRM.
Referring to the Blog [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/05/07/integrating-crm-using-sql-integration-services-ssis.aspx) I tried to establish a connection to CRM and load data into it.

Everything works fine, except the Script Component.
Here is the code in my Script Component:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    CrmService service = new CrmService();

    public override void PreExecute()
{
        base.PreExecute();

        CrmService service = new CrmService();
        service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        service.Url = "http://crm2011dev.myOrg.local/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx";

        CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
        token.OrganizationName = "myOrg";
        service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
        service.PreAuthenticate = true;          
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        contact Kontakt = new contact();

        Kontakt.firstname = Row.FirstName;
        Kontakt.lastname = Row.LastName;
        Kontakt.telephone1 = Row.Phone;
        Kontakt.emailaddress1 = Row.Email;

        service.Create(Kontakt);
    }
}
```

But when I execute the package, the following error occurs:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, > WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] 
>   parameters)
>      at CRM.Proxy.CrmSdk.CrmService.Create(BusinessEntity entity)
>      at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
>      at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
>      at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer Buffer)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, 
>   PipelineBuffer buffer)

That cannot be, I thought, because the user which runs the execution has full CRM rights (System Administrator role in CRM)!

So I tried to implement the code directly in the “Input0_ProcessInputRow” section:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    CrmService service = new CrmService();

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();               
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
    // here the part from the PreExecute() section:
        CrmService service = new CrmService();
        service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        service.Url = "http://crm2011dev.myOrg.local/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx";

        CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
        token.OrganizationName = "myOrg";
        service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
        service.PreAuthenticate = true;



        contact Kontakt = new contact();

        Kontakt.firstname = Row.FirstName;
        Kontakt.lastname = Row.LastName;
        Kontakt.telephone1 = Row.Phone;
        Kontakt.emailaddress1 = Row.Email;

        service.Create(Kontakt);
    }
}
```

...and it works !!!
So it cannot be a simple permission issue.

It seems, that the Script Component does not pass the credentials from the “PreExecute” to the “Input0_ProcessInputRow”... how can I fix that?

Has anybody an idea? Thanks in advance!

st4ff

Answer (score 0):

You are using default credentials so, is the user that runs the SSIS job a CRM user with the correct privileges?

You could, as a test, try to hardcode the credentials. Something like this:

```
service.Credentials =  new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

Also, is there any reason why you are using the 2007 endpoint. It will be deprecated if/when you upgrade to CRM 2013?